# Mysql complex group by following day rang

Tags: mysql, range, days

I have a table with a date column, from the table I want to count the number of items that were added before current date, and grouping following certain date rang.

For example:

all items added from day 1 to 7 are grouped un 7; 
 all items added  from day 1 to 14 are grouped under 14; 
 all items added from day 1 to 30 are grouped under 30;  all items added from day 1 to 60 are 
   grouped under 60;  from adday 1 to 90 are grouped under 90, and from 
   1 to beyond 90 should be grouped under “others”

Here is a illustration of what I really want:

[image]

The result I am expecting to have is something like this:

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need a table that contains list of number for your grouping needs.

```
CREATE TABLE `numbers` (
   `number` int(2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into numbers values (7), (14), (30); -- You can specify as you want
```

And then try this query:

```
select sum(if((day(datewrite)) <= number, 1, 0)) as 'Number Of Items', number as 'Since member of Days'
from test.b
left join (
    select number from numbers
) num on day(datewrite) <= number
group by number;
```

This should produce result as expected.